# Django tailwind custom arbitrary colors not working

Tags: css, django, django-templates, tailwind-css, tailwind-3

I've been using django with django-tailwind to build a website that involves color mixing. I take a bunch of colors from a database and mix them together. This results in new colors that I can't write down in the tailwind config and so I've been trying to use the arbitrary values custom colors from the documentation. The css for the color shows up correctly in my inspector but the color itself doesn't compile.

I've also noticed that if I manually enter the color hex anywhere in the code (on another element for example), all elements with that specific color code get rendered correctly so I'm guessing it's something to do with django-tailwind not compiling the colors since they are determined during runtime or something.

My django template code is as follows:

```
{% for day_obj in days %}
    <div class="flex flex-col bg-[{{day_obj.day.color}}]">
```

and here it is from the chrome inspector
[image]

But it doesn't work.
However, this

```
{% for day_obj in days %}
    <div class="flex flex-col bg-[{{day_obj.day.color}}]">
      <div class="flex items-center justify-between leading-tight">
        <h2 class="text-3xl font-bold">{{ day_obj.weekday }}</h2>
        <p>{{ day_obj.day.date }}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid grid-cols-{{ day_obj.habits|length }}">
        {% for habit in day_obj.habits %}
        <div class="bg-[{{habit|hex_color}}] text-white">&nbsp;</div>
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
      <div class="flex flex-col bg-[#82e153]">
```

will render all the elements correctly that have that specific color code: #82e153. Elements that are rendered from before also tend to stick around after I remove the manually-entered-hex-code but usually just stop rendering after a while (I assume due to some sort of caching of the color in the stylesheet)

Is there a way to make this work or should I just resort to using something else like the CDN? I really want to stick to django-tailwind for the time being.

Comment: Please add your code as text instead of a screenshot.

Comment: @Gabe I changed the code snippets

Answer (score 1):

*You probably figured it out by now, but for others that might run into this issue...*

The problem is caused by `{{ day_obj.day.color }}`, the tailwind processor needs to have a **static** value for this to work.

Normally with arbitrary values, what happens is this.

```
<!-- in your django tempalte -->
<div class="bg=[#ffaabb]">
...
</div>
```

```
// in the generated css

.bg-\[\#ffaabb\] {
   --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
   background-color: rgb(255 170 187 / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
}
```

If you use `{{ .. }}` for **arbitrary** values it will create a class name like the one above, and thats why you're css is not reflecting the color.

This is a link to the tailwind docs, its the older version. But I believe in v3 it still the same.

https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode

> Arbitrary values cannot be computed from dynamic values

`<div class="bg-[{{ userThemeColor }}]"></div>`

> Use inline styles for truly dynamic or user-defined values

`<div style="background-color: {{ userThemeColor }}"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use CSS variables for this. [See tailwind docs.](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors#using-css-variables) You could add a color to the tailwind config like:

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend:
      colors: {
        mixed: 'rgb(var(--color-mixed) / <alpha-value>)',
    }, 
  }
}
```

Now you can use the `bg-mixed` class in your html.

Setting the CSS var you can do with a style attribute:
`style="--color-mixed: 130 225 83"` (these need to be RGB values separated by a space). I do not know much about Django, but I think replacing the value by `{{day_obj.day.color}}` will work, because the browser will add the value to the CSS var, which will be used by the compiled Tailwind class.

```
<div class="flex flex-col bg-mixed" style="--color-mixed: {{day_obj.day.color}}">
```

You may need to add the initial value of the var to the `:root` in  the base layer in your `index.css`, like:

```
@layer base {
  :root {
    --color-mixed: 255 255 255; /* White */
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I did as you said and it shows up in the inspector that --color-mixed is an unknown property name. 

btw you're missing a curly bracket in your module.exports code snippet and a '"' in your second snippet. I'm just saying this in case I did something wrong by adding them.

Comment: I am sorry, I made a mistake with that. Fixed it in my answer. Also added that you might need to add the variable's initial value to the index.css.

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work. It again compiles correctly in the inspector but the value doesn't render until I manually change the value (even by just pressing space and then backspace) so it can re-compile.

Comment: I am afraid I do not know enough about how Django and Tailwind work together then, @YousefRadwan. I hope someone else can help.